# Update p:inputText from p:commandButton

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a `p:dataTable` where each row has a `p:commondButton` and an `h:outputText` to display a project's name. 
A click on the `p:commandButton` calls the `anfrageErfassenModel.applyProjekt()` actionListener and should immediately 
update the value in the `p:inputText` for `anfrageErfassenModel.anfrage.name`.

JSF page - anfrageErfassen.xhtml:

```
<h:form id="formAnfrageErfassen">

    <p:panelGrid columns="3" id="anfrage">
        <p:outputLabel for="name" value="#{bundle['anfrage.name']}"/>
        <p:inputText id="name" value="#{anfrageErfassenModel.anfrage.name}" required="true" />
        <p:message for="name" id="message4name" display="text"/>
    </p:panelGrid>

    <p:dataTable var="projekt" ...>
        <p:column>
            <p:commandButton icon="fa fa-check"
                title="Apply Project"
                update=":formAnfrageErfassen:anfrage"
                immediate="true"
                actionListener="#{anfrageErfassenModel.applyProjekt(projekt)}"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{projekt.name}"/>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Bean - AnfrageErfassenModel.java:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class AnfrageErfassenModel implements Serializable {

    private Anfrage anfrage; // with getter / setter

    public void applyProjekt(final Projekt projekt) {
        logger.entry(projekt);
        anfrage = anfrageRestClient.create();
        anfrage.setName(projekt.getName()); // take name from projekt
        logger.debug("anfrage.name=" + anfrage.getName());
        logger.exit();
    }       
}
```

The actionListener calls `anfrage.setName(projekt.getName())` which results that the model's value is set as expected
-> But the `p:inputText` is not updated!

I know that `immediate="true"` means, that the APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES phase is followed by the RENDER_RESPONSE phase!

What must I do to get the inputText field's value updated with the current value of the model?
Using `p:outputText` instead of `p:inputText` works, but I need the `inputText` because the field must be editable by the user!

I'm using Primefaces 6.0 on WildFly 10.0.0.Final.

Thanks and Regards,
Rainer

Comment: did you try to add `<p:ajax listner="#{managedBean.yourMethod()}" update =":Yourcomponante" />`  ???

Comment: @YagamiLight: Ajax is built-in in the `p:commandButton`. Adding an ajax tag is not needed there.

Comment: @Kukeltje believe me sometimes it does work

Comment: Did you check if the id you use in the update attribute of the commandButton is the right one? E.g. isn't the form by accident nested in a namingcontainer?

Comment: I would believe you if you have an explicit cases where it would be needed . You now say 'sometimes' .... I personally never needed to add an ajax tag in a commandButton to get it to update something. If updates did not work, it was 60% of the time a wrong reference (naming container missing) 20% of the time a typo and 20% of the time an error where the action/actionListener was not called and hence the update should not occur. And keep in mind that an outputText works! That would btw mean my comment about the naming container is invalid to

Comment: Did you try adding a `process="@this"` to the commandButton?

Comment: @YagamiLight: The default value of the process attribute is different between an ajax tag and the commandButton. That might have caused your 'difference'. But that could have been solved by doing as stated in my previous comment

Comment: I changed the commandButton to `update="@form"` without any change - inputText get's not updated.

Comment: @Kukeltje: adding `process="@this" to the commandButton solved the problem - Thank you very much! I'll add your comment as answer!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Kukeltje - adding `process="@this"` to the commandButton solved the problem!

Comment: It good practice on Stackoverfkow that if during comments, someone has the solution, to ask that person to post it as an answer. That way they gain reputation points for their effort. Now I personally don't always want the reputation point, but still. And an answer should also have some explanation on why it is the solution. Please improve the answer.